# Compilers for DOS32?

Tags: c++, c, dos, basic

Where can I get BASIC and C/C++ Compilers for MS-DOS?

Comment: Isn't DOS32 a contradiction in terms?

Comment: Ya. I miss understood the term.

Comment: No you can use DOS to load a 32 bit program,

Comment: @mgb, only if you use a DOS Extender, such as the HX-DOS extender. Though technically that's not really "using" dos to load a 32-bit program, it's exploiting the security weaknesses of dos to load a 32-bit program in spite of DOS's basic inability to do so.

Comment: http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Download This is the 32 bit C compiler used in Doom under DOS. Watcom C-produced code is switching to 32 bit protected mode when run.  iirc, Sea Graphics Viewer (DOS image viewer program) also uses Watcom C

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's DJGPP for C/C++.

http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/

Comment: This is the definite answer. I spent many happy years using DJGPP back in the day.

Comment: This is the answer, I can tell you from hard experience. That is, if you really do mean MS-DOS.

Answer (score 7):

Free (though not necessarily open source) Compilers that target MS-DOS (generally 32-bit but some may also still target 16-bit):

- [Digital Mars](http://www.digitalmars.com/download/dmcpp.html) 16 and 32 bit
- [DJ Delorie's DJGPP version of GCC for DOS32](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/) 32 bit only
- [Open Watcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Download) 16 and 32 bit

If C alone (without C++ support) is interesting to you, there's also these (I honestly have no idea how well these things might work on modern systems compiling modern source code - actually it's been so long since I've done anything in or for DOS that I don't know how well the 3 compilers above work for MS-DOS either)

- [DeSmet C](http://www.desmet-c.com/) 16 bit only
- [Turbo C 2.01](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/25636) 16 bit only

Answer (score 2):

Turbo C can compile c/c++

Comment: This can work, but Turbo C is not open source, sadly. Though you can download it for free, the licensing arrangement of programs compiled using this free version is somewhat unclear to me.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.digitalmars.com/ is what was once Zortech, the original 32bit flat memory model DOS compiler.

You can also use GCC either under cygwin or mingw.
The last MSVC to build DOS executables was IIRC 1.52 it's a free download if you have MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows 95 or later you can use the [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) version of gcc.  It won't give you a basic compiler though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't go wrong with DJGPP (best C++ support, LFNs) or OpenWatcom (multi-platform, also supports 16-bit). For BASIC, try FreeBASIC (which uses DJGPP's libc, assembler, linker but has its own compiler frontend).  http://www.freebasic.net